# How to open messenger lite on mobile from web Page

Tags: javascript, web, messenger

I am trying to set a button to go back in messenger lite app from a web page on click.

it works fine for messenger simply using a `window.open` with fb-messenger for messenger, but I tried to use some syntax such as fb-messenger-lite for messenger lite and it still going to messenger. If the app wasn't installed, it redirected me to messenger store page...

this is the simple code onclick that is working properly:

```
window.open("fb-messenger://user-thread/...");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on the application, every mobile application has a "Scheme" for url and if the application dose not support it than you wont be able to launch it with the url scheme... 
The App developer needs to open this option for you to use it, you could contact them or look at their API or Docs if exists.